# How do you source a JS file as a module in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to do the following:

```
module “git_file” {
  source = "git::https://githubXX.com/abc.js"
}

data "archive_file" “init” {
type        = "zip"
git_file = "${module.git_file.source}"
}
```

I am not able to make the above work. No matter if use https:// or ssh://

How do you source a JS file as a module in terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **module** block is for loading Terraform modules and their attending resources into your module under a particular module path. It cannot be used the way you intend.

> To call a module means to include the contents of that module into the
>   configuration with specific values for its input variables. Modules
>   are called from within other modules using module blocks:
>
> ```
> module "servers" {
>   source = "./app-cluster"
>
>   servers = 5
> }
> ```

Source: [Calling a Child Module - Modules- Configuration Language - Terraform Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module)

It's somewhat like import, require, or include in other languages. It cannot be used to download a file for use in a Terraform module.

You *could* use the [**http** data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/http/data_source.html) to do what you describe:

```
data "http" "git_file" {
  url = "https://githubXX.com/abc.js"
}

data "archive_file" “init” {
  type        = "zip"
  git_file = data.http.git_file.body
}
```

This is also unlikely to work as you expect. You would definitely need a raw source link to GitHub for it.

You should consider an alternative solution involving having abc.js in the same repository or using a [null_resource with a local_exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) to download it with a script.

```
resource "null_resource" "" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "git clone https://github.com/..."
  }
}
```

Then you'll have the files locally for your use the same way you would if you git cloned on your own shell. I don't recommend this. It is brittle and will likely interact strangely with other tools.

Comment: -how will i use null_resource to use it?

Comment: You need to get better at seeking these solutions independently. The answer you were looking for was readily accessible. Resourcefulness is a baseline expectation of this profession. I've updated the solution to provide the null_resource example as requested.